# Way to programmatically change iOS keyboard width?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

Is there a way to change the width of the iOS default keyboard? It takes up too much screen real estate (on iPad) and was wondering if there was an easy way to adjust its dimension without building a custom keyboard

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to change the height of the iOS default keyboard.
Even the custom keyboard you build will have its default size same as the iOS default keyboard.

You can get the dimensions of the default keyboard programmatically using the UIKeyboardNotifications.
[Managing the Keyboard](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW1)

There are 16 different heights of the default keyboard.
They can be different for landscape/ portrait, keyboard split/ non split, some other language keyboard(not english).