# How can I change the width of keyboard

Tags: ios, swift

Is it possible to change the width of the device's keyboard.Can anyone please help me with this?The keyboard should be inside the sidemenu viewcontroller.How to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, It  is not possible** to change the height or Width of the iOS default keyboard.if you want then  you need to  go for `custom keyboard Extension` Concept , for E.g   [tutorial1](https://www.appcoda.com/custom-keyboard-tutorial/) , [tutorial2](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/CustomKeyboard.html)

**Update**

for your concept `The keyboard should be inside the sidemenu viewcontroller.` in that time increase the revalWidth of your side menu when keyboard appears,  again resize the side menu width when Dismiss the Keyboard

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid this is not possible.

[Way to programmatically change iOS keyboard width?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32344654/way-to-programmatically-change-ios-keyboard-width)